# How to install Ubuntu 18.04 Server over an existing CentOS install

Tags: server

We have an existing machine with CentOS 7.4. We need to replace this with Ubuntu 18.04 Server. Can we do this via the CEntOS install or do we need to do this as a clean install.

Sincerely,

Arshad.

Comment: Do a clean install, much easier

Answer (score 0):

There's no reliable (or even sane) way from the CentOS installation to install Ubuntu overtop of itself.

You will need to do a clean installation.

Comment: You can do it in a chroot debootstrap https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/powerpc/apds04.html